# Apache's 000-default.conf - weird behaviour

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, virtual-host

I'm trying to achieve a redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com` (non-www to www).

My **`sites-available/example.com.conf`** file looks like this;

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAdmin unidan@example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

        ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

My **`sites-available/000-default.conf`** file looks like this;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin zuckerberg@facebook.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/default/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now.. when requesting `http://www.example.com` it will respond as requested. However, when requesting `http://example.com` it will render the request using the configuration in `000-default.conf`.

Unlinking `000-default.conf` from `sites-enabled/` will fix this issue, however this is not something I want to do (I want to keep a default behaviour for unknown requests).

What is the issue here? Why does the configuration in `000-default.conf` override the redirect?

Answer (score 2):

Your domain.com virtual host only specifies `www.example.com` as a name, therefore Apache will only *match* it when `www` is specified.

```
ServerName www.example.com
```

You probably want to use the following configuration instead:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

*Edit:* I am guessing, in your case, that Apache tries to match your virtual hosts in an order similar to the following:

```
www.example.com > default > example.com (80) > example.com (443)
```

Since the `default` host matches all requests sent on port 80, the two others would never be tested. This also explains why removing the default makes your configuration work correctly.

I am not very familiar with Apache's virtual host matching, but you may find more information about it on [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html).

Comment: What about the 2 virtual host configs beneath it?

Comment: It all depends on the order in which Apache tries to match the VirtualHosts. It seems like, in your case, the default host is tested right after *www.domain.com*. By the way, using `ServerAlias` for the www subdomain is quite a common practice. I added some more information in my answer.

Comment: Yeah but I want to issue the Redirect in the Apache layer. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want a redirect? Using both `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` will have Apache handle your requests through the correct virtual host, therefore there would be no need for redirection. If you want to force the use of `www`, I'd suggest you have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907348/force-www-via-htaccess) instead. This link uses .htaccess files but you may use your Apache configuration just as well.